# How to fix this KeyError? KeyError: 'PID' (Python language)

Tags: python, dataframe, keyerror

The "PID" is in the DataFrame tbh. The screen capture shows the problem and my code lines.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NMH6.png)
I tried to restart my kernel, but the error still occurred...

Comment: Hi @silencieuse, Welcome to SO, it's always nice to have the exact code block while asking questions, Please feel free to edit this question. 
Looking at the attached screenshot,  can you try doing `df.get("PID",0)`, here `0` is the default value which you can change as per your need. This will help you avoid `KeyError`.

Comment: add code in text format!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `df.apply(get_party)`, just use `df.PID.apply(get_party)` with `pid` as a parameter of `get_party` function.

```py
def get_party(pid):
  if pid < 2.0:
    return 'Democrat'
  elif pid == 5.0 or pid == 6.0:
    return 'republication'
  else:
    return 'Independent'

df['party'] = df.PID.apply(get_party)
```